# graphs and groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, graph-theory

In many papers we see a group which is constructed a graph from it and captures some information about the group. There are several ways of doing this, non-commuting graph, power graph, cayley garph,...but I am thinking about the inverse, if we start with a set of graphs can we put a group structure on this set of graphs? at first I need to define a graph operation which is Closure, Associativity,Identity element, Identity element. any idea?

Comment: You want each graph in your set to be an element of a group?  That's not exactly the "reverse" of the previous processes, which make one graph out of a group.

Comment: You can start with a graph and let it define a group. For example, right angled Artin groups (that is, RAAGs, also known as a partially commutative groups) are quite trendy at the moment. These are defined by taking a graph, then every vertex corresponds to a generator and every edge to a commuting relation between the generators. So a complete graph define a free abelian group and a graph with no edges will define a free group. These two classes of groups share certain properties, and so the question is do RAAGs also have these properties?

Comment: (You can also do the same but putting arbitrary groups on the vertices, so groups commute if there is an edge connecting them. Two unrelated concepts are studying free groups by viewing them as the fundamental group of graphs - look up Stallings' "topology of finite graphs", or studying "graphs of groups", which is to do with groups acting on trees.)

Answer (score 0):

If this of interest for you, you can get from every graph the **semigroup** of paths of the graph putting
$$
(a_1,\ldots,a_m)(b_1,\ldots,b_n)= \left \{
\begin{array}{l}
 (a_1,\ldots,a_m,b_2,\ldots,b_n) & \mbox{ if}\ a_m=b_1, \\
  0 & \mbox{ if}\ a_m\ne b_1.
\end{array}
 \right.
$$